# Windows 11 system storage is always changing

Tags: windows-11, disk-space

I got a problem using **Windows 11 Pro version 23H2**.
System takes up a lot of disk space

Every day I notice that the space on my system disk changes, day by day it gets bigger or smaller by itself.
The size of installed apps does not change, but *System & Reserved* does.

[Screenshot of System & reserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlSkG.png)

I need help, I don't understand if it's normal or not that the system takes **up 30 to 40+ gb** of space and changes from day to day. And how can I manage it properly

Especially noticeable is how the size of the *Hibernation file* changes (from 6 to 16gb) and the *Virtual memory* (from ~1gb to 3 and more gb)

Comment: Yes, it’s perfectly normal for Windows to take 30 GB+ in fact that’s one of its systems requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagefile.sys size is set by the size of virtual memory (VM). [You can control how much space is allocated](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-virtual-memory-size-windows-10) to VM, and if the *Initial size* is set to the same amount as *Maximum size*, it keeps the size constant, as well as helping avoid disk fragmentation.

As for total drive space requirements, 40 GB is likely the *minimum*, even for Windows Home. There are various ways to clean accumulating junk, such as Windows [Disk Cleanup](https://www.howtogeek.com/125923/free-up-disk-space-on-windows/), [cleaning up the WinSxS folder](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reclaim-space-reducing-size-winsxs-folder-windows-10), and using third-party tools, such as [Wise Disk Cleaner](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-disk-cleaner.html).

If your drive is small, either get a larger drive, or choose an OS that is less needy -- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ISO, **including** utility apps such as web browser, word processor, spreadsheet, database, email client, image viewer, archive manager, and drive utilities, is about *4 GB*, and might require just a few GB more while running.